# Is there an equivalent to "HttpContext.Response.Write" in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nopcommerce, httpcontext

I'm trying to append some HTML and JavaScript content on page using ActionFilter in ASP.NET Core 2.

In ASP.NET MVC, that can be done with:

```cs
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

but in ASP.NET Core that's not working.

I tried to implement with this:

```cs
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(stringBuilder.ToString());
```

But it makes my page completely blank.

I'm looking for a solution compatible with nopCommerce 4.0, which I use with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this

In a custom implementation of `INopStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)`:

```
application.Use(async (context, next) =>    
{
    using (var customStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Create a backup of the original response stream
        var backup = context.Response.Body;

        // Assign readable/writeable stream
        context.Response.Body = customStream;
        
        await next();

        // Restore the response stream
        context.Response.Body = backup;
        
        // Move to start and read response content
        customStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var content = new StreamReader(customStream).ReadToEnd();
        
        // Write custom content to response
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(content);
    }
});
```

And then in your custom `ResultFilterAttribute`:

```
public class MyAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Foo Bar");
            
            // Seek to end
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Seek(context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        catch
        {
            // ignored
        }

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

And the result

[image: Result HTML]

Comment: If we use this solution in nopCommerce, we are getting issue. 
In _INopStartup.Configure_ method, If we call **await next()** first and then **restore the response stream**, it will not load images and scripts on User side and gives error of **Response Content-Length mismatch:too many bytes written.**
If we first restore the response stream and then call await next() then it will give error in **filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Body.Seek() method not found**.

Answer (score 20):

The static and asynchronous method [`HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponsewritingextensions.writeasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is currently the preferred way of reaching this goal.

You can find it in the assembly `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

[HttpGet("test")]
public async Task GetTest()
    => await HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(this.Response, "Hello World");
```

Using the ASP.NET Core 6.0, you can write a simple response using Minimal API like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();
app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World");
app.Run();
```

[Source: MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: How would we put this in, for example, an if statement inside a method on a .cshtml.cs page?

Answer (score 11):

Response.Body.Write takes a byte array as an argument.

```
public void OnGet() {
    var text = "<h1>Hello, Response!</h1>";
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    Response.Body.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

or async version:

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() {
    var text = "<h1>Hello, Async Response!</h1>";
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
    await Response.Body.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Make sure to remove or comment our default content from razor page, since Response.Body.Write takes over page response
` @*
    @section Scripts {
        @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    }
*@`

Answer (score 1):

My code was no prepared for async execution, so i used:

```
Response.WriteAsync("text").Wait();
```

.Wait() make the execution waits for the Async Method complete execution to continue.

*I don't know if the performance is the best, but is already better than .Net Framework solution*

.Wait(): https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.writeasync?view=net-6.0

.WriteAsync(): https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-6.0