# Complete request execution from inner method in Web API

Tags: asp.net-core

I have API that based on ASP.NET Core 2.2 and I want to return result not from my public method that handles request but from an inner method.

```
public class UsersController : MainController
        {
            [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
            public IActionResult Get(int id)
            {
                var value = GetSomeValue();
            }

            private string GetSomeValue()
            {
                // and here I want to return result to user not even returning result to calling method `Get`
                return "";
            }
        }
```

I can set status code to response through `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode` and I know how to set body to the response but I don't know either could I return response to user from `GetSomeValue` method or not. May be somehow using `HttpContext`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really if this is what you're asking but here are my two cents:

> I want to return result not from my public method that handles request but from an inner method.

Well this is not trivial, what you're asking If I get it right is to manipulate the HttpContext so you start the response on an inner method instead of returning from your controller, which is the right way.

I don't know why you would want to do that but, I guess you can get some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350368/is-there-an-equivalent-to-httpcontext-response-write-in-asp-net-core-2)

In any case I don't get why don't you just:

```
return Ok(value);
```

like:

```
public class UsersController : MainController
{
    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var value = GetSomeValue();
        return Ok(value);
    }
    private string GetSomeValue()
    {
        // and here I want to return result to user not even returning result to calling method `Get`
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: That was not what I would like to do [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350368/is-there-an-equivalent-to-httpcontext-response-write-in-asp-net-core-2). I can write response body but I can't return it not through `IActionResult`. I tried to minimize controller method that handles request via making some actions in inner small method. And now I understand that returning result from inner method is not clear so it's not a good practice but anyway I'm interested if it's possible