# Why is there no Response.Write in asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, message

What's the workaround to display a simple message?
If I want to just display the value of a variable in the web page tell me something similar to Response. Write.

Comment: It's moved to `HttpContext.Response.Body` - you need to supply your own `StreamWriter` though.

Comment: "If I want to just display the value of a variable in the web page" - ASP.NET Core does not have a concept of "web pages" so your question is difficult to answer if you're still thinking along the old lines of `*.asp` and `*.php` files.

Comment: I want to display it in a cshtml page. Please give some sample code.

Comment: ok tell me how to display a simple message in a cshtml file

Answer (score 5):

`Response.Write` uses `System.Web` namespaces and it is used in Asp.NET Framework not Asp.NET Core.

> If I want to just display the value of a variable in the web page tell me something similar to Response. Write.
>
> tell me how to display a simple message in a cshtml file

It is not clear where does the variable come from or where do you want to use the `Response.Write`.

If you want to pass data from controller to view, you could use [ViewBag/ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.0#passing-data-to-views)

Action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "hello";
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@ViewBag.Title
```

If you want to just display a message in view you could use `HttpContext.Response.Body.Write`

```
public async Task Index()
{
      var str = "hello world";
      byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str);        
      await HttpContext.Response.Body.WriteAsync(bytes);
}
```

Refer to [Is there an equivalent to "HttpContext.Response.Write" in Asp.Net Core 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350368/is-there-an-equivalent-to-httpcontext-response-write-in-asp-net-core-2)

Answer (score 1):

As easy way to do this is by using the page model to write your value to the output
You do not need to use Response.write.
Here is a simple demo using a Razor Page.

1) Create new Razor page called NewPage in your Pages folder.

2) In your page model (NewPage.cshtml.cs) create a new public string named message.

```
    public class NewPageModel : PageModel{
        public string message;
```

3) Assign the message variable a value in the OnGet/OnPost method.

```
    public void OnGet(){
        message = "Hello World";
```

4) In NewPage.cshtml write the model value to the output.

```
    @page
    @model MyProject.Web.Pages.NewPageModel
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }
    @Model.message
```

Your value will be shown in the output.