# Asp.net Request.Write work around in Core5

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-5.0

There was a asp.net application created pages and controls dynamically using like

> Response.Write("");

Please let me know work around in Core 5.0 Blazor form

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47350368/is-there-an-equivalent-to-httpcontext-response-write-in-asp-net-core-2

Comment: "Work around."  Yeah, if you're moving from asp.net to Blazor, that's not the right word to be using.  Try something like: "Now that I'm using a new and infinitely better framework, what's the right way to do things?"